# Help Installing NXT-G On Mac 10.6.x

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, software, nxt-g

I'm failing to install NXT-G on Mac 10.6.x.  Whatever I try seems to end up with an error saying "A required file is broken" when I try to run the IDE.  Could someone talk me through the steps please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The drivers are probably not installed correctly.  You have to run the legodriver.pkg (by double-clicking on it) which you can find in the 'Parts' folder.

You should use this detailed [list of steps](http://www.dansanderson.com/blog/2009/12/did-you-get-lego-mindstorms.html) (and references). The legodriver.pkg is mentioned on point 5 of the fix for OS 10.6.